# overflow:hidden makes data disappear in IE

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I'm having a problem with IE. The page works fine in all browsers like shown below.

[image]

but in IE the data doesn't show up even though its there.

[image]

The problem is caused by the overflow:hidden attribute I use on the item template of the ListView. When I change it to any other value the data shows up in IE but of course the layout gets messed up in all browsers.

Here is the source code and the CSS http://jsfiddle.net/V5aCa/8/

And here is my code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="BookListView" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    onselectedindexchanged="BookListView_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server" cellpadding="1" id="tblBooks" style="">
          <tr runat="server">
              <td runat="server">
                  <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                      <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                      </tr>
                  </table>
              </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
         <div style="overflow:hidden">
            <div class="itemTemplateleftColumn">
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("~\\Static\\Images\\BookCovers\\{0}", Eval("CoverImageSmall")) %>' Height="120px" Width="90px" BorderColor="Gray" BorderWidth="1px"/>
            </div>
            <div class="itemTemplaterightColumn">
                <div class="titleRow">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="BookTitleLabel" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
                </div>
                <div class="nameRow">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="FirstNameLabel" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LastNameLabel" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' />
                </div>
                <div class="values">
                     <div>
                        value1
                     </div>
                     <div>
                        value2
                     </div>
                </div>    
                <div class="values">
                    <div>
                        value3
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="PriceLabel" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>' />&#8364
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:ListView>

</asp:Content>
```

I would appreciate any help on solving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've got a client side problem. Show us the client side code, not the ASP that generates it.

Comment: @Quentin It's in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/V5aCa/8/

Comment: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: @Quentin Do you mean I should include the source code and CSS in the question instead of using fiddle? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: As well as. Live demos are great. They shouldn't be required to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated] First, apply a css class or id to avoid inline styling.

Then, try to write `overflow:hidden !important` to prevent IE from applying that rule, this should do the trick!

```
.your-div-class{
  overflow:visible; /* This is default value, but reset it anyway */
  overflow:hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed... hidden is the default value of overflow, right?

Comment: I used this but again no change                #MainContent_BookListView_itemPlaceholderContainer div{
  overflow:visible; 
  overflow:hidden !important;
}

Comment: Did you delete the inlined "overflow:hidden" in your server side code (the first child of "ItemTemplate")? If you don't, the inline style will overwrite your externalized css. By the way, in your screenshot, it seems that the first child of the table is an empty tag instead of tr/td

Comment: I moved it to the externalized CSS because the layout gets messed up in the other browsers if I remove it. The empty tag is created by the ListView control.

Answer (score 0):

Apply minimum Height and Width for that div in Gridview and then apply overflow 
min-height: 110px;min-width: 150px;

Try this hope it will help!